# How to insert a column which sets unique id based on values in another column (SQL)?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-insert, create-table

I will create table where I will insert multiple values for different companies. Basically I have all values that are in the table below but I want to add a column `IndicatorID` which is linked to `IndicatorName` so that every indicator has a unique id. This will obviously not be a `PrimaryKey`.

[image]

I will insert the data with multiple selects:

```
CREATE TABLE abc                
INSERT INTO abc
SELECT company_id, 'roe', roevalue, metricdate
FROM TABLE1 
INSERT INTO abc
SELECT company_id, 'd/e', devalue, metricdate
FROM TABLE1
```

So, I don't know how to add the IndicatorID I mentioned above.

EDIT:
Here is how I populate my new table:

```
INSERT INTO table(IndicatorID, Indicator, Company, Value, Date)

SELECT [the ID that I need], 'NI_3y' as 'Indicator', t.Company, avg(t.ni) over (partition by t.Company order by t.reportdate rows between 2 preceding and current row) as 'ni_3y',
t.reportdate
FROM table t
LEFT JOIN IndicatorIDs i
ON i.Indicator = roe3 -- the part that is not working if I have separate indicatorID table
```

I am going to insert different indicators for the same companies. And I want indicatorID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to find the solution for my problem which seems to me very simple, although it took time and asking different people about it.
First I create my `indicators` table where I assign `primary key` for all indicators I have:

```
CREATE TABLE indicators (
    indicator_id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    indicator varchar(255)
);
```

Then I populate easy without using any `JOINs` or `CROSS APPLY`. I don't know if this is optimal but it seems as the simplest choice:

```
INSERT INTO table(IndicatorID, Indicator, Company, Value, Date)    
SELECT 
    (SELECT indicator_id from indicators i where i.indicator = 'NI_3y) as IndicatorID, 
    'NI_3y' as 'Indicator', 
     Company, 
     avg(ni) over (partition by Company order by reportdate rows between 2 preceding and current row) as ni_3y,
    reportdate
FROM TABLE1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your "indicator" is a proper entity in its own right.  Create a table with all indicators:

```
create table indicators (
    indicator_id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    indicator varchar(255)
);
```

Then, use the `id` **only** in this table.  You can look up the value in the reference table.

Your inserts are then a little more complicated:

```
INSERT INTO indicators (indicator)
    SELECT DISTINCT roevalue
    FROM table1 t1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM indicators i2 WHERE i2.indicator = t1.roevalue);
```

Then:

```
INSERT INTO ABC (indicatorId, companyid, value, date)
    SELECT i.indicatorId, t1.company, v.value, t1.metricdate
    FROM table1 t1 CROSS APPLY
         (VALUES ('roe', t1.roevalue), ('d/e', t1.devalue)
         ) v(indicator, value) JOIN
         indicators i
         ON i.indicator = v.indicator;
```

This process is called *normalization* and it is the typical way to store data in a database.

Comment: But the indicator is not a column that exists in my table. I create it as 'NI' as 'indicator', so I cannot use Cross Apply.

Comment: @Yana . . . Huh?  The `CROSS APPLY` generates the indicator value.

Comment: I edited my description of the problem. Hopefully it won't cause further confusion

Answer (score 0):

DDL and INSERT statement to create an indicators table with a unique constraint on indicator.  Because the ind_id is intended to be a foreign key in the abc table it's created as a non-decomposable surrogate integer primary key using the IDENTITY property.

```
drop table if exists test_indicators;
go
create table test_indicators (
  ind_id        int identity(1, 1) primary key not null,
  indicator     varchar(20) unique not null);
go

insert into test_indicators(indicator) values
('NI'),
('ROE'),
('D/E');
```

The abc table depends on the ind_id column from indicators table as a foreign key reference.  To populate the abc table company_id's are associated with ind_id's.

```
drop table if exists test_abc
go
create table test_abc(
  a_id  int     identity(1, 1) primary key not null,
  ind_id        int not null references test_indicators(ind_id),
  company_id    int not null,
  val           varchar(20) null);
go

insert into test_abc(ind_id, company_id) 
select ind_id, 102 from test_indicators where indicator='NI'
union all
select ind_id, 103 from test_indicators where indicator='ROE'
union all
select ind_id, 104 from test_indicators where indicator='D/E'
union all
select ind_id, 103 from test_indicators where indicator='NI'
union all
select ind_id, 105 from test_indicators where indicator='ROE'
union all
select ind_id, 102 from test_indicators where indicator='NI';
```

Query to get result

```
select i.ind_id, a.company_id, i.indicator, a.val
from test_abc a
     join test_indicators i on a.ind_id=i.ind_id;
```

Output

```
ind_id  company_id  indicator   val
1       102         NI          NULL
2       103         ROE         NULL
3       104         D/E         NULL
1       103         NI          NULL
2       105         ROE         NULL
1       102         NI          NULL
```